# How to handle null Model on all controllers aspnet core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have lots of models setup for my web api, none of which have any attributes against them.  Here is a simple controller example

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync([FromBody] ChartModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Now if a user tries to upload invalid data type in the model, for example, types a letter into a number property, then my controller recieves null.

What is the best, simplest way to handle this?  I want to return a BadRequest if the model is null for these particular methods.

I could add something like below to each and every method.

```
if (model == null)
    return new BadRequestObject("Invalid model");
```

But i am sure there must be something that i can do and is cleaner and tidier, i just dont know what

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` tells you if any model errors have been added to `ModelState` read more about [ModelState](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/)

Comment: Even if you havent setup any attributes on your models?

Comment: If nothing else, a global action filter could do that :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it on top of your controller method

```
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync([FromBody] ChartModel model)
{
     // your code goes here
}
```

and you don't have to check every time in your code if ModelState is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

On way is to Implement an ActionFilter Attribute, do your check before the method execution and return error response if you find any invalid parameters.

For example this (.NET 4.5 code!) will return BadRequest if it finds ANY! Parameter which is null.

```
public class ParamCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var args = actionContext.ActionArguments;
        if (args.Any(arg => arg.Value == null))
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Null params");
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Then just decorate your methods with the ActionFilter or register it globally .

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ParamCheck]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test(SummarySyncParams pars)
    {}
```